# Soaking fruits in fruit juice

Tags: cake, fruit

Can I soak fruits in fruit juice for a fruit cake? If yes, do I need to boil the juice? Thanks a lot.

Comment: *Can* you?  Sure.  Will it have any sort of benefit to either the cake or the fruit?  That depends.  Posting a recipe would help get you a good answer, as would more detail on what's behind your concern.  Are you asking about safety, how to get the best flavor out of the fruits, or something else?

Comment: Are you talking fresh fruit or dried? Are you dissatisfied with the results you are getting, if so why?

Comment: Patent for Grapples: Forming a grape flavoring mixture including a methyl anthranilate compound;applying to exocarp of pome fruit after harvest adsorption through the pericarp http://www.google.com/patents/US7824723

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, but I'm guessing you want an esthetic effect somewhere in your recipe... maybe using the juice somehow as an after glazing effect or something like that? Post your true final purpose :)

Answer (score 1):

> Can I soak fruits in fruit juice for a fruit cake?

The short answer is yes, if you mix different fruits in different juices the flavor will most likely be confusing but overall, expect it to be sweet.

> If yes, do I need to boil the juice?

If the juice is fresh (from a can or a box that you just opened, or freshly pressed juice from fresh fruits) it does not need to be boiled, unless you want to cook your fruit before integrating them to the cake. Of course if the juice isnt fresh you should not use it.

Boiling fruit juices could result in loss of liquid and you might not want that. What is it you're trying to accomplish ?